# How to add a link to Cocoa CFUserNotification Box

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to display a small message box with "Ok", "Cancel" button, some text and an internet link.

I am using CFUserNotification class, but it does not has a specific link option. I would like link to take me to browser, while the dialog is still in the air.

I searched through the internet but did not find any option to do it.

If there is no way to do it with CFUserNotification, what is the other way?

Comment: google "CFUserNotification site:opensource.apple.com" or similar ; clickable links are not supported out of the box in cocoa (nstextfield). So it has to be called in code after pressing Ok button. This is a tip not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If showing a help button is acceptable, rather than a link, then you should be able to use `NSAlert`.  Make the alert, call `setShowsHelp:YES`, and implement the `alertShowHelp:` method on the alert delegate to go to the link in question.  This should be quite a simple and straightforward solution.  If you really need to show the actual link, though, then you will need to make your own panel; make a nib with a window, run the window as a sheet, etc.  There will be lots of examples available through Google.  This approach will be a lot more work, though; for simple notifications to the user, it is probably best to go with the solutions that Apple supplies, and Apple, in their infinite wisdom, has not given `NSAlert` an `NSAttributedString` message so putting a link attribute in the alert message is not presently possible as far as I know.

Comment: NSAlert is part of Cocoa; I thinks he doesn't want to use the framework

Comment: The question's title says "Cocoa", so it seems to me he is using it already.

Comment: I think that he doesn't know what he wants. There is no reason to use (doesn't make sense) CFNotificationBox if you import Cocoa framework.

Comment: Yes, that's probably true.  :->

Comment: @Iron-Eagle, it seems to me that I have answered your question.  If so, please accept the answer.  If not, please clarify why not.

Comment: I wish the people here would appreciate the time and effort we have to do. Most of the time they don't want to accept is because they await copy-paste solution... Which is sad